# .NET Core 1.1 Identity error after successful login - Authorization failed for user: (null)

Tags: asp.net-core

I've got a MVC .NET Core 1.1 web app using identity for user management.

After successful login, I redirect the user to the home page.  That controller has the [Authorize] attribute, but when it's trying to load the page I get redirected to the login page, and the following error is in my debug window

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:64496/  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService:Information: Authorization failed for user: (null).
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker:Information: Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult:Information: Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware:Information: AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was challenged.
```

It seems as though my User object got lost after login.

This code is running on Azure just fine and worked for me 6 months ago locally when I made the last change.  Today I opened up the solution to look at an issue the customers reported and now I cannot login.  There have been no code changes, but I've updated VS and .net on my machine.  I'm wondering if those updates could be the cause.

Login Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(1, "User logged in.");
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning(2, "User account locked out.");
                    return View("Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

StartUp class

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(x => x.ValueCountLimit = 5000);

            services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBContext")));

            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DBContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

                // Lockout settings
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Users/Account/LogIn";
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LogoutPath = "/Users/Account/LogOff";
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.AccessDeniedPath = "/Users/Account/AccessDenied";

                // User settings
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

            services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
            {
                //set all tokens to expire in 30 days.  Default is 1 day and for new accounts that seems to be too short
                options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
            });

            // Add application services.
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
            services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

            // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache for sessions
            // more info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
                {
                    // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                    //options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                    options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
                });

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            loggerFactory.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Shared/Error");
            }

            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Shared/Error/{0}");

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentity();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areaRoute",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            SeedData.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what happened, but it just started working.  I haven't changed any code, but now after login the Identity exists and it's all good.